# How to print list of elements to console with protractor

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I'm new to Stack Overflow. In my application I have to create a group and verify the group is created or not by searching the group in the list. If the group is in list, I have to open the chat box of that group. All this scenario should be automated using protractor. I'm new to protractor so could you please provide an explanation with the answer

1. Trying to loop through group names to check if created.
2. Tried simply printing group names in console, but still unsuccessful.

Attempt in protractor to print group text:

```
this.getElements = function(){
  element.all(by.css('some text')).getText().then(function(text){
      console.log(text);
  });
};
```

HTML Snippet:

```html
<ul class="list-unstyled users-list components">
      <!----><q4s-spinner _nghost-c4=""><div _ngcontent-c4="" class="spinner" hidden=""></div>
</q4s-spinner>
      <!----><div class="user-profile-container">
        <!---->
        <!----><div class="row each-user">
          <div class="user-profile-picture">
            <!---->
            <!----><div>
              <!----><img class="img-fluid user-picture" src="http://13.126.104.174/static/6286/BMP.jpeg">
              <!---->
              
            </div>

            <!---->
          </div>
          <div class="user-profile-details">
            <div class="row">
              <p class="group-name-text">myGrpW</p>
              <!----><span>
                <!---->
              </span>
            </div>
            <!----><p class="group-details-text"></p>
            <!---->
            <p class="group-members-text">2 Members</p>
            <!----><span>
              <!----><p class="admin-text"> Admin </p>
              <!---->
            </span>
          </div>


          <!----><div class="more-action-image-position">
            <div>
              <img class="img-fluid more-icon" placement="left" src="assets/images/more-icon.svg">
              <!---->
            </div>
          </div>

          <!---->
        </div>
      </div><div class="user-profile-container">
        <!---->
        <!----><div class="row each-user">
          <div class="user-profile-picture">
            <!---->
            <!----><div>
              <!----><img class="img-fluid user-picture" src="http://13.126.104.174/static/6286/BMP.jpeg">
              <!---->
              
            </div>

            <!---->
          </div>
          <div class="user-profile-details">
            <div class="row">
              <p class="group-name-text">newWWW</p>
              <!----><span>
                <!---->
              </span>
            </div>
            <!----><p class="group-details-text"></p>
            <!---->
            <p class="group-members-text">3 Members</p>
            <!----><span>
              <!----><p class="admin-text"> Admin </p>
              <!---->
            </span>
          </div>


          <!----><div class="more-action-image-position">
            <div>
              <img class="img-fluid more-icon" placement="left" src="assets/images/more-icon.svg">
              <!---->
            </div>
          </div>

          <!---->
        </div>
      </div><div class="user-profile-container">
        <!---->
        <!----><div class="row each-user">
          <div class="user-profile-picture">
            <!---->
            <!----><div>
              <!----><img class="img-fluid user-picture" src="http://13.126.104.174/static/6286/BMP.jpeg">
              <!---->
              
            </div>

            <!---->
          </div>
          <div class="user-profile-details">
            <div class="row">
              <p class="group-name-text">AutoWa</p>
              <!----><span>
                <!---->
              </span>
            </div>
            <!----><p class="group-details-text"></p>
            <!---->
            <p class="group-members-text">3 Members</p>
            <!----><span>
              <!----><p class="admin-text"> Admin </p>
              <!---->
            </span>
          </div>


          <!----><div class="more-action-image-position">
            <div>
              <img class="img-fluid more-icon" placement="left" src="assets/images/more-icon.svg">
              <!---->
            </div>
          </div>

          <!---->
        </div>
      </div><div class="user-profile-container">
        <!---->
        <!----><div class="row each-user">
          <div class="user-profile-picture">
            <!---->
            <!----><div>
              <!----><img class="img-fluid user-picture" src="http://13.126.104.174/static/6286/BMP.jpeg">
              <!---->
              
            </div>

            <!---->
          </div>
```

Comment: I have added the picture of application code, can you guys see it ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to check for text in an element, you need to use and `expect`.

```
expect(element.all(by.css('some-text').getText()).toContain('expected text');
```

You also need to make sure you are using the proper [CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css_selectors.asp). To get the group name from your example html, you could use `p.group-name-text`. The entire expect would look like:

```
expect(element.all(by.css('p.group-name-text').getText().toContain('MyGrpW');
```

If you are only tryng to print the text to the console your code would look like

```
element.all(by.css('p.group-name-text').getText()).then(function(text){
  console.log(text);
});
```

Comment: element.all(by.css('p.group-name-text').getText()).then(function(text){
  console.log(text);
});   ==> I tried this one and getting error : Failed: by.css(...).getText is not a function

Comment: I think css locator starts with dot(.), may be for that or else for getText it is showing that error.

Answer (score 0):

```html
var totalList_grps = element.all(by.css('p.group-name-text'));

    totalList_grps.getText().then(function(text){
        console.log('Total list of joined groups : ' + text);
      });
```

Sorry there,s nothing problem in css, needed a small change, I tried the above code it works fine for me

Comment: For printing total list of groups in console it is working and output for total list is displaying like this, "Total list of joined groups : Party,Innovation,capsLock,Gym,Sunrisers AW,Big Boss"

When i try to find a group name by using your code, it is displaying => Expected [  ] to contain 'Big Boss'.
i search for name Bigboss.