# How to search for a particular text from list of names using if else condition in protractor?

Tags: if-statement, protractor

```html
var totalList_grps = element.all(by.css('p.group-name-text'));

    totalList_grps.getText().then(function(text){
        console.log('Total list of joined groups : ' + text);
      });
```

Tried the above code for printing list of group names.
Got Output :Total list of joined groups : Party,Innovation,capsLock,Gym,Sunrisers 
            AW,Big Boss.
    Now i need to search for a particular name using if else condition and i tried the second set of code, but its not displaying any output not even a error.

```html
totalList_grps.getText().then(function(itemList) {
            expect(itemList).toContain('Big Boss');
        });
```

[Here is developers code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50739408/8511716)

Answer (score 1):

1) use `by.cssContainingText()`:

```
var bigBoss = element(by.cssContainingText('p.group-name-text', 'Big Boss'));

// then you can call click(), getText(), getAttribute('') on found element as following:
bigBoss.click();
```

2) use `elements.filter()`:

```
var bigBoss = element.all(by.css('p.group-name-text'))
    .filter(function(it){
        return it.getText().then(function(txt){
        console.log('txt: ' + txt);
        return txt === 'Big Boss' || txt.includes('Big Boss');
        });
    })
    .first();
```

3) use `await` with combination of `if/else`

```
var allNames = element.all(by.css('p.group-name-text'));
var length = await allNames.count();
var matchedIndex = -1;

for(var i=0;i<length;i++) {
    var name = await allNames.get(i).getText();
    if (name === 'Big Boss' || name.includes('Big Boss')) {
        matchedIndex = i;
        console.log('matchedIndex = ' + matchedIndex);
        break;
    }
}

var bigBoss = allNames.get(matchedIndex);
```

We can implement option 3 without using `await`, but the code will be not easy readable and more complex than current.

FYI, If you want to use `await/async`, you need to disable protractor promise management (know as control flow). You can't use both in your code at same time.

Comment: I tried 2nd option of elements.filter, but its not returning any text and not even throwing any error.
Can u please complete the code for first option using by.cssContainingText();

Comment: I updated some code in option 2, to trace the text of each name in the list, and change the condition to accept if name contains 'Big Boss', not only exactly equal to 'Big Boss'.  It's better to given the HTML code of the name list in your question(don't add HTML by comment)

Comment: `filter` doesn't return text, it's returning the first element that matches what you are looking for which is an `ElementFinder`. You need to call `bigBoss.getText()` to get the text of that element.

Comment: Here is the HTML code [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/q/50739408/8511716) @yong
Can we do it using if else condition ?